# Two ssl certificates on same server with two different IP addresses

Tags: ssl, iis-7

I have two Sharepoint web applications running on the same server.  We want to use the following IP Address:port configurations:
- first site: IP Address: x.x.x.22 port 443
- second site: IP Address: x.x.x.60 port 4430

When I go to IIS for the second site and select the .60 IP address and port 4430 and then select the certificate I'm getting the following message:

"The binding is already being used by a product other than IIS.  If you continue, you might overwrite the existing certificate for this IP Address/Port combination.  Do you want to use this binding anyway"

I don't want to click Yes because I'm not sure what this is going to overwrite.
The strange thins is that I've tested this before with a self-signed certificate and it worked fine.  But now it's not working (I tried it with both the official ssl certificate and a self-signed one).

One thing I noticed is that if I edit this binding and select "All Unassigned" as the IP address rather than the one I'm trying to force then I am able to assign the certificate with no problem.  But, if I do that, is it going to end up using IP address x.x.x.22 or x.x.x.60? I would prefer to explicitly specify the IP address.

Comment: "All unassigned" means "Listen on all ip addresses". In your case, since the IP/port combo of .60/4430 is already taken, your second site would most probably only listen on .22/4430. Apart from that, what @Enigman said.

Answer (score 4):

Try checking to see if there is another service listening on that port:

From a command prompt:

```
netstat -an | find ":4430"
```

Look for anything listening on that port. That will help ascertain if there is another service on your host that is configured to listen on that port. If that is the case then you would need to either change the port that service is listening on or change which port you want your second sharepoint site to listen on.

If you find there is no conflict (I suspect that perhaps it got confused about the binding) you should be able to bind the second site with your desired certificate.

Answer (score 0):

How I made my IIS 7.5 work with multiple IP's and multiple Certificates using IP and Host name mix.

From your post you've installed your certificates and my guess is you have the chain installed as well.

Open up your MMC console. 
Start > Run > MMC.exe
File > Add/Remove
Select Certificates.
Use Local Computer

Once you have the console open go to Certificates > Personal and select one of your certificates. 
Right click and select Properties. 
Your friendly name will be displayed, type an * asterisk in front of your friendly name. 
Click Apply then Ok to close.

Now select your IIS website and click on Bindings. 
Select your IP and leave the port defaulted to 443 and Select HTTPS
Now you'll have a field for your host header which you will leave blank. 
Select your certificate for this IP address.

Repeat for your second IP leaving both on port 443.

Should work on IIS 7 I tested it on IIS 7.5 and the rest is just a guess. 
(This old post needed updating so I posted the answer for IIS 7.x)